# How to get certain items out of a list

Tags: python

I want to return certain items from a list with a specific instance.

I'm a little unclear as to how to use isinstance but from the little I know about it, it seems like the best way to do it.

```
animals = [Hen(0.25), Hen(0.6), Hen(1.0), Hen(8), Rooster(0.25), Rooster(0.6), Rooster(1.0), Cow(1.0), Goat(1.0), Duck(1.0)]


def get_class(animals):
    if not isinstance(animals, Hen):
        return NotImplemented
    return animals
```

I want to have the list animals now only have Hen(0.25), Hen(0.6), Hen(1.0), Hen(8).  Any help would be appreciated, but I would prefer just guidance rather than the answer.

Comment: Is `Hen()` a function ?

Comment: It is a class.  Sorry for not making that clear.

Answer (score 5):

You could probably use list comprehension to achieve this:

```
new_animals = [x for x in animals if isinstance(x, Hen)]
```

This basically builds a new list that only contains items that are an instance of the Hen class.

Kind of unrelated, but to represent the `Hen()` class in a clean way like you want, you could do something like this:

```
In [25]: class Hen():
    ...:     def __init__(self, number):
    ...:         self.a = number
    ...:     def __repr__(self):
    ...:         return "Hen({})".format(self.a)
    ...:

In [26]: h = Hen(4.5)

In [27]: h
Out[27]: Hen(4.5)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The only thing is it is returning the object type not the actual object.  This could very well be a mistake on my part

Comment: Not sure I follow. You should be getting a new list containing the actual objects.

Comment: It returns this [<src.hen.Hen object at 0x10cd34160>, <src.hen.Hen object at 0x10cd34128>, <src.hen.Hen object at 0x10cd39f28>, <src.hen.Hen object at 0x10cd54d30>]

Comment: @CollegeStruggles That's what you should be expecting. Those are the 'string representations' of your object instances. If you do `print(Hen(0.25))`, you'll get something that looks like that.

Comment: Oh so is there a way to return it in a list as Hen(0.25), Hen(0.6), Hen(1.0), Hen(8)?

Comment: You can override the `__str__()` or `__repr()` function(s) to show whatever you like. I edited the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample code

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

class Car:
    def __init__(self, make, year):
        self.make = make
        self.year = year

def get_person_objs(objs):
    return [obj for obj in objs if isinstance(obj, Person)]

persons = get_person_objs([Person("Peter", 12), Person("Tom", 23), Car("Toyota", 1998)])

for person in persons:
    print(person.name)
```